# How can I create table with PITR enabled through API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, point-in-time

How can I create a dynamo db  table with PITR enabled through API in java??

This is my create table request

```
CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest()
                .withTableName(properties.get(TABLE_NAME).textValue())
                .withKeySchema(this.buildKeySchema(properties))
                .withAttributeDefinitions(this.buildAttributeDefinitions(properties))
                .withProvisionedThroughput(this.buildProvisionedThroughput(properties))
                .withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(this.buildGlobalSecondaryIndex(properties))
                .withBillingMode(properties.get(BILLING_MODE).textValue());
```

I want to add PITR enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PITR is enabled using seprate api call [UpdateContinuousBackupsRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/UpdateContinuousBackupsRequest.html).

The Java call maps to [UpdateContinuousBackups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateContinuousBackups.html) AWS API.